# nodejs ractive and consolidate html comment issue

Tags: html, ractivejs

I am using consolidate.js and ractive templates, which by default strip out comments.  I am trying to add some html logic in the page that does something like this:

```
<![if IE]>one thing<![endif]>
<![if !IE]>another thing<![endif]>
```

However ractive removes the comments.  I know you can allow comments in ractive, by setting stripComments false, but I don't know how to do that through consolidate.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `consolidate.ractive()` is passed directly to Ractive, so you can do this:

```
cons.ractive(path, { stripComments: false, user: 'Tobi' }, function () {});
```

In case you want to separate your data from Ractive config, you can do this instead:

```
cons.ractive(path, { stripComments: false, data: { user: 'Tobi' } }, function () {});
```

If the object doesn't have the `data` property, the whole object will be used as `data` as well.